# PHP - limiting <li> tags in a <ul>

Tags: php

I have the following HTML output;

```
<ul>
 <li>Test 1</li>
 <li>Test 2.</li>
 <li>Test 3</li>
 <li>Test 4</li>
 <li>Test 5</li>
 <li>Test 6</li>
 <li>Test 7</li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do, is display the same HTML, but with only the first 4 `<li>` tags, i.e.

```
<ul>
 <li>Test 1</li>
 <li>Test 2.</li>
 <li>Test 3</li>
 <li>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Is there an easy way I can do this in PHP?

Thanks

EDIT:

The data is coming from:

```
$data = $product->getDescription();
```

It is stored in the DB as the HTML content, I am currently displaying it using the above code;

Thanks

Comment: Where's this data coming from? Are you generating this list, or this is a static HTML? Please add more details.

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? Is it just HTML that you want to remove the 3 other `<li>` elements for? Or a database that provides these values?

Comment: Why PHP? If test5 - test7 doesn't carry confidential info. It's good to do this via JavaScript.

Comment: if it's dynamic data presumably it's getting created in a loop - limit the loop, or you could limit the SQL query itself if it's just used for this purpose.

Comment: @fabrik @Jakub the data is coming from a CMS, which saves the HTML. I am simply then pulling out the data. I cannot limit the SQL call as this is just pulling out all the content from a particular field.

Comment: You can edit fn. getDescription or manipulate the result HTML with PHP's DOMDocument lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm yes..

Depending on where the data is coming from, I am going to assume it is a db of some sort and you have it in an array():

```
$databasevalue = array(); //stuff from database goes here / dragons
echo "<ul>";

for ( $counter = 0; $counter < 4; $counter ++) {
  echo "<li>".$databasevalue[$counter]."</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

Can't offer more without better question details.

Answer (score 1):

How is data coming from ?

If this data comes from an array you can slice it with array_slice function

```
$list = array_slice($input, 0, 4);
// $list now only having first 4 item.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
  echo '<li>' . $i . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Outputs:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<ul>
```

Someone else answered with a good one (requires [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), PHP5) but has been deleted:

```
<?php
$data = '<ul>
           <li>Test 1</li>
           <li>Test 2.</li>
           <li>Test 3</li>
           <li>Test 4</li>
           <li>Test 5</li>
           <li>Test 6</li>
           <li>Test 7</li>
         </ul>';


$ul = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

$li = $ul->li;

echo '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
for($i = 0 ; $i < 4 ; $i++)
{
  echo '<li>'.$li[$i].'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using database, you should use "LIMIT" in your SQL, otherwise [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will do the job.

don't forget: documentation is your best friend (especially in php)